# CGridView functionality of searching constants

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have constants id coming from database and i am displaying them in my CGridView using following code

```
'columns'=>array(
    'id', 
    'name',
    'email',
    array(
        'name' => 'deleted', 
        'value' => '$data->deleted == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"',//like this 
     ),
)
```

Now when i search through CGridview, it only searches by number i.e 1 or 2. I need to search by Yes or No. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your model is User and you are displaying that table's CGridView, in the UserController get your parameter like this :-

```
if(isset($_GET['User'])){
    $model->setAttributes($_GET['User']);
}
if(isset($_GET['User']['deleted'])){
    $value = $_GET['User']['deleted'];
    if($value == 'Yes' || $value == 'yes'){
        $model->setAttribute('deleted', 1);
    }
    if($value == 'No' || $value == 'no'){
        $model->setAttribute('deleted', 0);
    }
}
```

Using this you can search the field 'deleted' by 'Yes' or 'No'

**Update :-**

You can use the following code to have a dropdown menu as filters in CGridView

```
$filter = array(
    '0' => 'No',
    '1' => 'Yes'
);
...
array(
    'name' => 'deleted', 
    'value' => '$data->deleted == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"',
    'filter' => $filter
),
```

This will give you a dropdown with filters specified in the array.

Comment: its good! but this does not extend smart search functionality of CGridView.

Comment: @Namelus Check the updated answer for smart search functionality.